# data from oracle between dates

Tags: oracle

I have to get data from an Oracle Database that are 2 weeks older from to-date.

Its a complex query and I have this condition in the where clause.

I have tried to use between. But in vain . I am sure I'm making some silly mistake in working out the between.

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy') || to_char(sgs.status_Date,'mmdd'),'yyyymmdd' )
    between (trunc(sysdate)) and trunc(sysdate) - 14
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is this some kind of anniversary calculation? You're taking the day+month from `sgs.status_Date`, but using the year from `sysdate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @valex says, you need to swap the order of the expressions. As the [documentation for the `BETWEEN` condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions011.htm) says:

> ... the value of
>
> ```
> expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3
> ```
>
> is the value of the boolean expression:
>
> ```
> expr2 <= expr1 AND expr1 <= expr3
> ```

Your version has

```
your_date between trunc(sysdate) and (trunc(sysdate) - 14)
```

which is equivalent to

```
trunc(sysdate) <= your_date and your_date <= (trunc(sysdate) - 14)
```

... which can never be true - `your_date` would have to simultaneously be *after* today, and *before* two weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

You should change BETWEEN dates as soon sysdate-14 < sysdate and should be first

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy') || to_char(sgs.status_Date,'mmdd'),'yyyymmdd' ) 
between (trunc(sysdate) - 14) and (trunc(sysdate))
```